# MySQL compare dates in a column to today

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of around 6000 records with a date column amongst other columns which represent the deadline for a query. I need to compare the date in the column to todays date which I understand is done something like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE_TO_COMPARE, CURDATE());
```

However, I then have another comlumn I want to set to that date difference. So for each date, I need to compare, insert the difference in the column `difference_in_days`, iterate to the next date and repeat.

I am also invoking this function whenever a certain page on my site is loaded using AJAX and PHP/PDO

My SQL knowledge isn't that extensive, how can I achieve this.

Table is kinda of like

```
    field 1, field2, field 3, date_to_compare, field 4, field 5, difference_in_days       
    |       |       |       | 2016-04-20      |        |       |                   |
    |       |       |       | 2016-04-25      |        |       |                   |
    |       |       |       | 2016-04-22      |        |       |                   |
    |       |       |       | 2016-04-27      |        |       |                   |
    |       |       |       | 2016-04-29      |        |       |                   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sonds like you want to do an update?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET difference_in_days = DATEDIFF(date_to_compare, CURDATE());
```

This will update every record in the table to the diff of the current date.

**However**, this will require you running the update every day, if you want that column to maintain relevance.

**Alternative Approach:**

If you're not querying this a lot, you may be better off using a view, which will update real-time every time you query it.

```
CREATE VIEW diff_view_name AS
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(date_to_compare, CURDATE()) AS difference_in_days
FROM table_name;
```

Then you could query it using:

```
SELECT * FROM diff_view_name;
```

Comment: So simple. How did I not realise that. Thankyou

Comment: @MrDansk - Plase check my edit / suggestion for a view.

Comment: I looked at having it as a stored procedure to run the query daily at X time but I dont think I have permissions/ the requirements are not activated on the server. Can you give me an overview of what a view does differently. My intention is to just run the query when the page has loaded, refresh the table and then users will see the latest values so it should stay relevant.

Comment: A view is a pseudo-table, with "columns" defined by the output of the query.    When you query the view I defined above, it will calculate the difference_in_days column real-time and output the results as if it were a table.